# Git GUI on Windows not working with self-signed SSL certificates - gives errors (fatal: SSL certificate)

Tags: git, ssl, certificate, gui

I'm using git GUI on Windows 7. I need to clone the repository and simply want to just use it.

However, when cloning, pulling, pushing to/from repo with self-signed certificate, I'm getting this error:

[image]
[image]

I tried to do some workaround:

[image]

And checked the path `C:\Users\student\.git` to see what I have in my config file:

[image]

However, I still can't get this work. Does anyone have any clue? How to work with git gui and self-signed certificates?

---

**Summing up:**

I have a server where I installed a Git server. I secured the server with self-signed certificate. I created a repository, lets call it X. Now I have problems with clonning/pushing/pulling any repository on my Git server, when using the git gui.

However, when I switched to git cmd, clonning/pushing was ok, when I used those commands:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false push
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://...
```

I tried to edit my configuration file located in `C:\Users\student\.git` by using `git config sslVerify=false` as admin. However, although I have `sslVerify = false` in my config file, I still need to use `git -c http.sslVerify=false` when using git cmd (but let's say, I'm ok with that).

So basically, I need a way to skip the SSL certificate checking when using git gui (its totally secure, I'm using it only on my local network). The question is how to do it with git gui? Is there any option that will set once and for all, that I want to skip the certificate verification part working with git gui?

Comment: Have you installed the self-signed certificate on the machine in question?

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, I didn't. How should I do it?

Comment: Install the certificate like you would any other SSL certificate in Windows.  I have an answer that goes into depth how to add a certificate to the certificate store I find repeating answers not to be enjoyable.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok, I managed to do it - there is no result, I still can't clone the repository

Comment: Please use text rather than screenshots, so search works for future visitors, and add some details to your title to get some views. Also please add what you've done (according to your comments) to your question. Thanks & success.

Comment: Try to run git GUI from the command prompt rather than from the Windows start menu. Try also to set 'Standard (Fast, Semi-Redundant, Hardlinks)' cloning.

Comment: @harrymc: Aldready did it, please see my edit.

Comment: Could you comment on the answers in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008309/how-do-i-set-git-ssl-no-verify-for-specific-repos-only) ?

Answer (score 8):

Please post the output of `$ git config --global --list`.
The command for disabling SSL checks would be `git config --global http.sslVerify false`.

Get the certificate as a `.pem` file and set git to trust it `$ git config --global http.sslCAInfo /path/to/cert.pem`.

Comment: Please read carefully. I already did `git config --global http.sslVerify false`. The command `git config --global --list` shows me the list of clonned repos, that's all.

Comment: No, you did it without the `--global` option. `git config --global --list` should give you a list of all set global config options. If it shows you cloned repos (WTF?) something is wrong with your git install.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry - you are right. The result is: http://s11.postimg.org/4wrjfko9f/test.png. Now I don't have the message about SSL erros, but a new error came out: `fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`. Since it's my own repository on my own server, I do have rights. What might be wrong now? I did `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` as well, with no effect. Im using the url with my name, for instance: `https://yak@my.server.org/repo.git`.

Comment: How was the repo created? Can you `ssh gituser@serverIP`? What does `git push --verbose` say?

Comment: Also it seems like there is no repository set in your config. Does `.git/config` has the remote `url` parameter set to your server?